# Is "hic" the implicit subject for "compulit" in this sentence?

Tags: syntax

This sentence is from the book "De antiquitate regum Norwagiensium", and was written by Theodoricus Monachus.

> Hic consuluit ei fugam et quodammodo compulit, ut in Rusciam pergeret, ubi et diem obiit.

Thoughts: I understand that "hic" is the subject for the verb "consuluit" in this sentence. But I am unsure about "compulit". Compulit is clearly a verb, and "hic" is the noun which this verb is referring back to, but I am not sure whether the subject is implicit for "compulit" or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are two parallel clauses, the second one elliptical, in which repeated *hic* is omitted. You could translate it as, "he / this man advised him/her to flee and in some way made him/her proceed to Ruscia".